# reading file to list<integer>

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am trying to read a text file in that contains numbers separated by commas. the file is large and may contain up to a few thousand numbers. i need to add these numbers to a list

`List<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

what would be the best approach to take? I am currently reading in the file like this;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\generated30-1.cav"));
     String line = null;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
     {
          sb.append(line.replaceAll(",",""));
          if (sb.length() > 0) 
          {
              sb.append("\n");
          }
     }
 } 
 catch (IOException e) 
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } 
 finally 
 {
     try 
    {
        if (br != null) 
        {
            br.close();
        }
     } 
     catch (IOException ex) 
     {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
 String contents = sb.toString();
```

Comment: The code above reads strings, not integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are separated by commas, you should **not** be removing the commas. I would use a `Scanner`. I would use `try-with-resources` instead of an explicit `close()`. And I would `split` each line on comma (`\\s*` globs optional whitespace). Like,

```
List<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
File f = new File("D:\\generated30-1.cav");
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(f)) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            listIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return listIntegers;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your input file does not contain spaces after the commas, then you should not be replacing the commas, as if you have multi digit numbers, you will not be able to differentiate between where the number starts and ends. Instead just append `line`:

```
sb.append(line);
```

And then you can do:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(contents.split(","))
                           .map(Integer::valueOf)
                           .collect(toList());
```

Which will create a stream from the `Array` created by `split` and then map them to int's and then collect them to a `List`

Comment: *I am trying to read a text file in that contains numbers separated by commas.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is off of the `String` the OP creates after replacing the commas

Comment: `sb.append(line.replaceAll(",",""));` is going to give OP a `String` like `1357434642` isn't it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That depends on the input file. In my experience it is customary to have a space after the comma. Like `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`

Comment: @GBlodgett I appreciate your answer however in this case there are no spaces between the values only commas

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely try and leverage the `Files.lines` as of JDK8:

```
List<Integer> result;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream.map(s -> /* perform your mapping operation here */)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

reading:

- [Introduction to Java 8
  Streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams-introduction)
- [Java 8 Map, Filter, and Collect Examples](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-map-filter-collect-of-stream-in-java-8)
- [The `map` method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)